# TIP120 transistor overheating with heatsink

Tags: transistors, heat, npn

[image: Circuit Diagram]

The transistor gets really hot even though I am using a heatsink. Have I connected something wrong?

Comment: Drop your base resistor to 200 ohms.

Comment: Your using PWM on a transistor that reacts slowly to changes in drive current. Try a fast npn or use a mosfet if you can drive the gate with at least 10 volts. Another option is to lower the PWM frequency.

Comment: I guess "slowly" depends on. Usual PWM frequencies of 1-2-10kHz shall make no problem for a transistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check the wiring of the transistor, its pinout is B-C-E which is not too intuitional. E goes to GND
- TIP120 is a bipolar transistor, dropping 0.7V when it is fully on. Assuming your motor draws like 2A, this is 1.4W of heat, which is hot by design
- In order to reduce wasting power, you can pick a MOSFET instead of this BJT. Pick e.g. IRFU2405 or AP20N15GI-HF - any N channel incremental mosfet will do. Less on-resistance means less power waste. In short, if you pick a MOSFET rated for 40A, it will essentially have no losses at 1-2A and will make no heat at all.
- Note that the MOSFET has to be a logic-level mosfet, i.e. a device which can turn fully on for less than 5V. The types I am suggesting are logic level MOSFETs.
- You don't need a series resistor between Arduino and the G of a MOSFET. However it is a very good idea to use a pulldown resistor of 1K..10K between G and GND. This ensures that the MOSFET is always OFF if the arduino is not driving its outputs (for example during reporgramming the Arduino).

Not related to the original problem:

- Note that the DPDT relay connection is fishy. It is not very likely that you can actually drive a relay coil directly from a port output, so you might wish to use a small bipolar transistor or a small FET to drive the relay coil. Even if you have the relay coil working, remember that you have a protecting diode missing. Similarly as you need diode for the motor, you need a similar protecting diode for the relay coil, otherwise when turning off the relay, the energized coil may destroy the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The base resistor is way to high. VBE(on)=3V, if your arduino outputs 5V, then Ib=2V/1.1k=0.5mA -> Ic=hfe*Ib=1000*0.5=500mA - this is not saturated what you have is variable resistor like operation of transistror, not on/off control needed for PWM.